# Demistifying Firmware

Tags: operating-system, firmware

[Firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware) - What exactly is this? I know that it isn't a piece of code which just helps in communicating with the hardware since it is the device driver's function.

I guess it is something more complex than that. All the time I see firmware updates for my mp3 players and smartphone. In smartphones I see that after a firmware update the OS's version is bumped up e.g., from Ice Cream Sandwich it goes to Jelly Bean (Android). Does this mean that firmware is an alias to OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firmware is just software that is programmed into a device. In the example you used, the OS would qualify being called firmware. In other devices, it could be less sophisticated than iOS or Android, for example, a lot of DVD players and Blueray players have a firmware component, so do smart TV that are Internet enabled and routers, for instance.